# How can I leave UAC on but set programs for which it doesn't prompt me?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, uac

I want to leave my UAC settings unchanged but every time Notepad++ starts, I get a UAC prompt. Is there a way to set exceptions for known programs?

[image]

Comment: OH MY GOD! What a horrible theme you have...

Comment: OMG! Windows 7 with Windows Classic theme. Fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer to your broader question, but np++ should only be prompting you if you try to start it as an administrator. If you're not doing that yourself, double check that the compatibility settings don't say "Run this program as an adminstrator" (Right click on notepad++.exe -> properties -> compatibility).

Comment: Ahh, I have to run it as an administrator because of some of the files I use it to edit....

Comment: @Matt: Then change ACLs on those files.

Answer (score 1):

No, I really don't think there is.

I have to run Visual Studio 2008 as Administrator, and I've never been able to figure out a way to suppress the dialog *just* for VS2008.

Comment: This seems like a poor oversight on MS' part

Comment: Aye, Matt. Aye.

Answer (score 1):

There is a work-around that utilizes the task scheduler, see [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-administrator-mode-shortcuts-without-uac-prompts-in-windows-vista/). This is supposed to work for both Vista and 7.